# Convert Json array key's as csv column name and values

Tags: json, r, dplyr

I am parsing a json data to write a csv file. I am using **tidyjson** package to do this work.

In some point I need to print all the subjects value below in a separate columns and score as a value. Meaning Physics, Mathematics will be a column name and score will be there value.

```
{
  "results": {
    "subjects": [
      {
        "subject": {
          "name": "Physics",
          "code": "PHY"
        },
        "score": 70
      },
      {
        "subject": {
          "name": "Mathematics",
          "code": "MATH"
        },
        "score": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried as below:

```
json_data %>%
  as.tbl_json %>%
  gather_array %>%
  spread_values(user_id = jstring("user_id")) %>%
  enter_object("results") %>%
  enter_object("subjects") %>%
  gather_array("subjects") %>%
  spread_values(score = jstring("score")) %>%
  enter_object("subject") %>%
  spread_values(subject = jstring("subject")) %>%
  mutate(Physics = case_when(.$name == "Physics" ~ score)) %>%
  mutate(Mathematics = case_when(.$name == "Mathematics" ~ score))
```

But this shows multiple rows for one student. I need to show single row with each subject and score as a column value.

Comment: You example JSON is not syntactically valid. Would you mind running `dput(json_data)` and including so that it's possible for other users to reproduce your example?

Comment: the "json" has been fixed, but an example of desired output wld help folks help you. `jsonlite::fromJSON(jsontxt)` makes a nice nested data frame structure that's easily workable with dplyr & purrr

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr! The provided JSON does not include "user_id" or anything that would indicate the records belong to an individual student. A more complete example is needed.

Comment: Sorry @steven please ignore the "user_id" key.  in this json data I have more then 500 keys that's why I just included this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this shows multiple rows for one student. I need to show single row with each subject and score as a column value.

That means, your need a unique row based on subject name? In that case you can use [aggregate](http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html)

if you have a data frame named `df` like,

```
subject <- c("phy", "math", "phy", "math")
Score <- c(10, NA, NA, 20)
df <- data.frame(subject, Score)
```

then,

```
aggregate(x=df[c("Score")], by=list(subjectName=df$subject), max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

output

```
subjectName Score
    phy       10
    math      20
```

Comment: Thanks @Emu this has solved my partial problem. I am also looking for some tidyjson solution.